Xdebug is not installed on docker container
I'm using this dockerfile to create an image with all the needed php extensions
#Imagen base de PHP 8.2 con Apache y Xdebug 3
FROM php:8.2-apache

# Instalar dependencias de AMQP, Xdebug, y extensiones necesarias
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    librabbitmq-dev \
    zip \
    curl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd pdo pdo_mysql zip \
    && pecl install amqp xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable amqp xdebug

# Configuración de Xdebug
RUN echo "xdebug.mode=debug" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_port=9003" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

# Habilitar módulo de Apache para el archivo .htaccess
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Exponer el puerto 9003 para Xdebug
EXPOSE 9003

# Directorio de trabajo en el contenedor
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Copiar archivo de configuración de Apache
COPY apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

# Instalar Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

# Instalar Symfony CLI
RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash \
    && mv /root/.symfony*/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony

# Iniciar el servidor Apache y PHP
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

but when I check on phpinfo() I see that the xdebug extension is no t on the list,using php-8.1 and xdebug-3.1.1 it works but with this versions the extension is not installed. I don't know what is wrong
